# get_edit_post_link visible for non-logged in users?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attachment

I want to grab get_edit_post_link from the attachment page so I can get information(product id) on which product was that image uploaded. Based on that I want to create related products.

Everything is working for logged in users but no for non-logged in users.

I get this link like:

```
get_edit_post_link($post->post_parent, 'raw');
```

Is it possible to show that link also for non-logged in users or is there maybe some alternative to achieve this?

Thanks for help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is not visible because logged out users should not be able to edit the post/product.

If you only need the product_id, you already have it, it's $post->post_parent

If for some reason, you really need to have the edit url, you can copy the original function code from here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_edit_post_link/
into your own function and remove lines

```
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ) ) {
        return;
    }
```

But you probably don't have to do that

Comment: Hello, thank you - this product id was exactly what I was looking for!